# How to change the size of a collection view cell after adding content to that cell

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, collectionview

I have successfully made the first collection view cells change in size as I add more cells to the second collection view. Now I need the space between the first collection view cells to be consistent

[image]

Comment: You want to remove that big space between the two collection views? You’d just set the vertical spacing constraints between the two collection views. Or perhaps easier, just have a single collection view with two sections. Then the flow layout will take care of all of that spacing for you. The question is whether you really want two independently scrolling collection views or a single one that takes care of all of the spacing automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using dynamic cell sizing with.

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {